# Read non-printable character from a file

Tags: java, parsing, exception, integer, readfile

I'm trying to read a character as an integer from a file and I receive an exception of NumberFormatException:

`Java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 " java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:554)
        at Main.main(Main.java:9)`

I'm pretty sure it's from the file, as it can be reproduced only when I copy the text to the file, when typed manually, it parses properly.
My question is: how can I avoid this exception and make that "4" to be parsed to the variable? The line where I parse it is: `int m = Integer.valueOf(inputFile.readLine());`

Comment: Is 4 on its own line in this file? If so, that non-printable character might be a carriage return used in windows systems.

Comment: It's just 4, without the quotes, the console puts the number between them. Yes, it might be the carriage return, but how can I remove it? As I can't refer to an actual character which is not printed.

Comment: try to use `int m = Integer.valueOf(inputFile.readLine().replaceAll("[^\\d]+", ""));`

Comment: Thanks, man! Can you post your comment as answer, please? I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are some special characters in your input, to avoid this problem you can use :

```
int m = Integer.valueOf(inputFile.readLine().replaceAll("[^\\d]+", ""));
```

Which mean replace any non digit with empty